# PHP: Get data from array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this query on my controller:

```
$this->db->select('t1.act_id, t2.login, t1.cust_name, t1.act_type, t1.act_detail, t1.date_added, t1.date_modified, t1.act_notes, '
             . 't3.category, t1.total_time, sum(t1.total_time) as total')
            ->from('activity as t1')
            ->join('user as t2', 't1.user_id = t2.user_id', 'LEFT')
            ->join('customer as t3', 't1.cust_name = t3.cust_name', 'LEFT')
            ->where('t2.login', $user)
            ->where('MONTH(t1.date_added)', $month)
            ->order_by('t1.date_added', "desc");

    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();        

    $data = array('title' =>'Sales Report'." - ".$user,
        'user' => $result);
    $this->load->view('admin/report/vw_report_excel', $data);
```

I want to post this SUM value

> sum(t1.total_time) as total

but I kept getting error, saying that "Trying to get property of non-object"

here's how I called it on my view (vw_report_excel):

```
<?php echo ($user->total); ?>
```

how is the correct way to call or declare it?
Regards

here's my view, I want my SUM exclude from the table/loop.

```
<?php $i=1; foreach($user as $xuser) { ?>
                 <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $xuser['act_id']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $xuser['login']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $xuser['cust_name']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $xuser['act_type']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $xuser['act_detail']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $xuser['date_added']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $xuser['date_modified']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $xuser['act_notes']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $xuser['category']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $xuser['total_time']; ?></td>
                 </tr>
                 <?php $i++; } ?>
<td><?php echo count($user); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo ($user->total); ?></td>
```

Comment: use foreach loop to get your data

Comment: I suppose `result_array()` gives you result as __array__.

Comment: this is why i hate query builders....

Comment: I added my view, I want the SUM to be outside of  the loop/table. thanks

Comment: use (object) $result... check my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Codeignitor Generating Query Results Manual Guid](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html)

***result_array()***

> This method returns the query result as a pure array, or an empty
>   array when no result is produced. Typically you’ll use this in a
>   foreach loop, like this:

So use `foreach()`

```
foreach($user as $usr){
 echo $usr['total'];
}
```

***Or use:-***`<?php echo $user[0]['total']; ?>`   (Based on your code modification in your question)

Comment: bingo, that's what I looking for. thank you kind sir.

Comment: @Syns  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 1):

Use `foreach loop` to get your data

```
foreach($user as $usr){
 echo $use['total'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this as you returned array not object

```
<?php echo ($user[0]['total']); ?>
```

If you want exactly like `$user[0]->total` then change `$result = $query->result_array();` to `$result = $query->result();`

As you getting single row there are more efficient way to avoid indexing like `$user[0]['total']`. Just use `row_array()` instead `result_array()`

```
$result = $query->row_array();
```

If you use that then no looping required and you can now use direct like

```
<?php echo $user['login']; ?>
```

Comment: I added more details, I need to extract the array but I want the total to be separated. is that possible? thanks

Comment: NO if you use `SUM` then only you can get single row. Answer edited, check now @Syns

Answer (score 1):

Since you retrieve an array as result with `$result = $query->result_array();` , you need to access it with numerical index and associative arrays. Hence if you want to access the first record;

```
<?php echo $user[0]['total']; ?>
```

Or if you want to traverse through all the results

```
<?php foreach( $user as $rec) echo $rec['total'];
//or
for($i=0,$count = count($user);$i<$count;$i++) echo $user[$i]['total']; ?>
```

**PS** the `for` loop is faster if you want to traverse