# Getting Group By value

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Based on my question earlier [Get Data from Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49549627/php-get-data-from-array/)

it turns out that in only shows one record with completed SUM value.
I've been trying to add `GROUP_BY` clause like this:

```
$this->db->select('t1.act_id, t2.login, t1.cust_name, t1.act_type, t1.act_detail, t1.date_added, t1.date_modified, t1.act_notes, '
             . 't3.category, t1.total_time, SUM(t1.total_time) as total')                
            ->from('activity as t1')                
            ->join('user as t2', 't1.user_id = t2.user_id', 'LEFT')
            ->join('customer as t3', 't1.cust_name = t3.cust_name', 'LEFT')                 
            ->where('t2.login', $user)
            ->where('MONTH(t1.date_added)', $month)
            ->group_by ('t1.user_id');
```

Unless I remove the SUM statement, the result still the same one record with complete SUM.

meanwhile if I change the `GROUP_BY` parameter into (`t1.act_id`) which is the primary key of that table, all records showing but the sum isn't (it only show SUM value of the first record only).

Any help would be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Your use of `GROUP BY` is technically incorrect, and your query makes no sense.  Review the basic rules of using `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen check my answer below, does it technically correct? if it doesn't please kindly add me some suggestion. thank you